# Resolve named dependency with Dagger 2 after the class is initialized

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2 for the dependency management of my Java application.

I have the following structure:

```
public interface SecondaryService 
{
    void doSomethingElse(String data);
}

public class SecondaryServiceFirstImpl implements SecondaryService 
{
    public void doSomethingElse(String data)
    {
       // Do something else
    }
}

public class SecondaryServiceSecondImpl implements SecondaryService 
{
    public void doSomethingElse(String data)
    {
       // Do something else
    }
}

public interface MainInterface
{
    void doSomething(String data);
}

public class MainService implements MainInterface
{
    private SecondaryService secondaryService;
    private DatabaseService databaseService;
    public MainService(SecondaryService secondaryService, DatabaseService databaseService)
    {
       this.secondaryService = secondaryService;
       this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

  public  void doSomething(String data)
  {
     String name = databaseService.getName(data);

    // Resolve the NAMED SecondaryService based on the name property and
    // use the implementation.
  }
}
```

And here is the Dagger Module code:

```
@Module
public class DependencyRegisterModule
{
    @Provides @Named('first')
    SecondaryService provideSecondaryServiceFirstImpl ()
    {
        return new SecondaryServiceFirstImpl ();
    }

    @Provides @Named('second')
    SecondaryService provideSecondaryServiceSecondImpl ()
    {
        return new SecondaryServiceSecondImpl ();
    }

    @Provides
    DatabaseService provideDatabaseService ()
    {
        return new DatabaseServiceImpl();
    }

    @Provides
    MainInterface provideMainInterface(SecondaryService secondaryService, DatabaseService databaseService)
    {
        return new MainService (secondaryService, );
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a `SecondaryService` interface that is implemented by two classes. I want to resolve the named dependency for the `SecondaryService` based on a parameter, that I get from the database inside a method in the `MainService`.

Is there a way to do this? If this does not work with a `Named` dependencies, is there another way to do this?

So far I have used a factory pattern, but it is very hard to manage, as I have to pass the dependencies of the classes inside their constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`@Named`—or `@Qualifiers` in general—are intended to be used if you need 2 objects of the same kind, e.g. injecting a `String username` and `String email`. In this case a qualifier could be used to distinguish between those objects.

In your case it seems that you want *either* one object *or* the other. In your case you should use different modules if you want to take a clean approach, or add an if/else to your module in the constructor.

### Use a base class

```
@Module
public abstract class ServiceModule {
    @Provides
    public abstract SecondaryService providesServcie();
}
```

Then just create 2 sub classes of this module and provide the needed service respectively.

When creating your component just supply the right implementation of your module

```
if(1 == 1)
    new MyComponent.Builder().add(new OneServiceModule()).build();
else
    new MyComponent.Builder().add(new OtherServiceModule()).build();
```

And remember, you don't have to duplicate your other `@Provides` methods, since you can just use multiple modules with the component.

### Use an if/else construct

```
@Module
public class DependencyRegisterModule
{
    private int whichModule;

    public DependencyRegisterModule(int whichModule) {
        this.whichModule = whichModule;
    }

    @Provides
    SecondaryService provideSecondaryServiceSecondImpl ()
    {
        return whichModule == 1 ? new SecondaryServiceSecondImpl() : new SecondaryServiceFirstImpl();
    }
}
```

I hope I don't have to explain how if/else works ;)